# "How much is it important" or just "How is it important" (without much)?

Tags: word-choice

Which among the two sentences is correct?

> 1) How **much** is it important?
>
> 2) How important is it?

Context: my friend told me that something is very important to him. I need to ask him again how (much?) important it is.

Comment: Second one should be *How important is it?*

Comment: You might hear "How *very* important is it?" if you want to bump the importance up a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal way is **How important is it?**

A good rule is:
If you are asking about a *quality*, say *How*.  (Another way to think of it is, if you could answer with *very*, use *how*.)

> How tall are you? (very tall)
>   How angry is he? (very angry)
>   How far is the city? (very far)

If you are asking about an amount of a mass noun, say *How much*.

> How much wool do we have? (five pounds of wool)
>   How much food does it eat? (three cans of food every day)
>   How much trouble has it caused? (a great amount of trouble)

If you are asking about the number of a countable thing, say *How many*.

> How many flowers did you use?  (ten thousand)
>   How many feet tall is he?  (six)
>   How many problems has it caused? (only one)

Because *important* is a quality, the correct way to say it is **How important is it?**

Comment: Now I am going to add a comment to my own answer to say that you will sometimes hear people speaking very informally say things like, **"It's important?  Exactly how much is it important?"**